# How to change tibble date column?

Tags: r, forecasting, tibble, facebook-prophet

So I have this date column in a `tibble`, which I was going to use for prophet forecasting.
The problem is that my timeseries, which contains daily data, shows up in the tibble at 4 minute intervals instead of daily. I have used the time series for other forecasting models so I know there is nothing wrong with the timeseries itself.

My question is: how to change the tibble dates to daily data starting at the first day, so I can forecast 56 days into the future using prophet?

I used the following code, where nn51 is a timeseries with frequency = 365.25.

```
nn51t <- nn51 %>% 
  tk_tbl() %>% 
  mutate(index = as_date(index)) %>% 
  as_tbl_time(index = index)

nn51t <- nn51t %>% 
  rename(
    ds = index,
    y = value
  )

fit51 <- prophet(nn51t)
future51 <- make_future_dataframe(fit51, periods = 56, freq = 'day')
forecast51 <- predict(fit51, future51)
plot(fit51, forecast51)+ ggtitle("Prophet forecast of NN5_101")
```

The dates in the tibble look like this:
[tibble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEXGT.png)

The data can be downloaded from http://www.neural-forecasting-competition.com/downloads/NN5/datasets/download.htm

Comment: Hm, I can't find the data column with  4 minute intervals.

Comment: No that is exactly the problem. It is daily data, but when I convert it to a tibble it changes to 4 minute intervals, but I want the daily intervals in my tibble.

Comment: but in the image of the tibble you posted, the index is of class 'date'; there is no indication of the data being in a 4 minute interval. Can you provide some output where you see the 4 minute interval?